# Ansible Lookup Plugin only returns 'NOMATCH' result

Tags: ansible

I am practicing lookup plugin on Ansible.

I try to find a match from the following local csv file lookup.csv.

```
$ cat lookup.csv
Bruce Wayne,Batman,Human
Clark Kent,Superman,Alien
Diana Prince,Wonder Woman,Deity
Wally West,The Flash,Human
John Stewart,Green Lantern,Human
```

The playbook is:

```
$ cat lookup.yml
- hosts: localhost
  user: test
  become: yes
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Lookup the SuperHero for BRUCE WAYNE {{ lookup('csvfile','Wayne file=lookup.csv delimiter=, default=NOMATCH') }}"
```

I believe it should return the match **Bruce Wayne,Batman,Human**

Instead, it returns the following:

```
$ ansible-playbook lookup.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Lookup the SuperHero for BRUCE WAYNE NOMATCH"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

what am I doing wrong with the play?.

Answer (score 1):

The [csvfile plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/csvfile.html#csvfile-read-data-from-a-tsv-or-csv-file) says:

> "... looks for the row where the first column matches keyname ... "

It must be an exact match. See [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/csvfile.py#L120). I don't know how to submit the key with space. Single-word key works fine. For example

```
msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', 'Bruce_Wayne file=lookup.csv delimiter=, default=NOMATCH') }}"
```

This plugin returns only one parameter. The module [read_csv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html#read-csv-read-a-csv-file) seems to be robuster option.

Comment: Yes, space is the problem there in the first column, thank you.